# Adding requests on aws-api-gateway to aws-sqs through an integration, failures even though "version" is specified

Tags: integration, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I've an AWS Api-Gateway resource that I tried configuring to add a message to AWS-SQS, however when I try sending a request to the api I get a response:

```
{
  "Error": {
      "Code": "MissingParameter",
      "Message": "Version is missing.",
      "Type": "Sender"
  },
  "RequestId": "the-multicharacter-request-id-blah-blah"
}
```

I have linked the two services in the integration taband the permissions policy is the below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried adding in api-gateway permissions to the policy,  adding a `Version` parameter in the header,  starting the setup from scratch again.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Version' here specifies which version of 'SQS' service to use and should be specified as a query parameter and not the header e.g.:

```
?Version='2019-05-09'
```

'Version' specified in the policy refers to the version of the policy language.

This was a case of RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this due to a different root cause:  make sure the "Action Type" is set to "Use path override" if you don't intent to use "action override"

[image: Screen shot of "Action Type"]

Answer (score 0):

In the mapping template of your API gateway should be:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$util.urlEncode($input.body)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JlHV.png)